# How to get server URL on load balancer

Tags: angularjs

We are using load balancer to service angular application , each back end server is invoked , is it possible to know URL of server which service d the request using existing angular service's, i tried  $location but it gets browser URL, which is of load balancer

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but instances URL shouldn't be publicly accessible when using a load balancer. Instances could add a [`Server` header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.38) to their responses though.

Comment: I actually wanted to set different API URL based on which serve r proceesed the request

Answer (score 0):

This is not about `angular` rahter it is about server side.
In case of `.net` you can put a key in you `web.config` and serve this to your client